# How to set kibana ELASTICSEARCH_URL parameter

Tags: docker

Docker for windows: 2.0.0.3(31259)

I run a elasticsearch and kibana in docker. elasticsearch is run .But kibana can not run . It always try to connected http://elasticsearch:9200 .I set 
the ELASTICSEARCH_URL kibana command. But not work

request http://localhost:5601/. Kibana server is not ready yet

```
docker run -d --name d-elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.1.1

docker run -d --name d-kibana -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://192.168.0.73:9200 -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.1.1
```

kibana docker log: 
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-06-05T08:21:26Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}

Answer (score 0):

In version 7, Kibana uses a different environment variable: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS

```
docker run -d --name d-kibana -e "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://192.168.0.73:9200" -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.1.1
```